# Variable importance plot

Tags: plot, label, random-forest, vip

I'm working on variable importance plot from random forest regression and want to apply variable labels to y-axis instead of cryptic variable names using the VIP package for ease of interpretation.

How to modify the code to add labels on y axis?

My current code:

````
library(randomForest)
library(vip)
model1 <- randomForest(y ~ .,
                      data=train,
                      mtry = 8,
                      ntree=500,
                      import[enter image description here][1]ance=TRUE,
                      proximity=TRUE)

plot_rf_1 <- vip(model1, 
                 num_features = 6,
                 include_type = TRUE,
                 geom = "point",
                 horizontal = TRUE,
                 mapping = aes_string(fill="var.labels"),
                 aesthetics = list(color = "blue", shape = 16, size = 3)) +
                theme_light()
grid.arrange(plot_rf_1, nrow = 1)```
````

Variable importance plot:

[image]